# How do i replace %2F in my ajax requested URL?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url-rewriting

Im using jQuery, my problem..

my URL looks like this after an ajax request (using hashchange function to enable history) :

`mysite.com/Content/#Disc%2Findex`

I want it to look like this:

`mysite.com/Content/#Disc/index`

I noticed this line in my js:

`url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');`

Does this have anything to do with it? when i stick an `/` in between the quotes it works but my content doesnt load.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
unescape(url)
```

to convert the %2F to a /. The url.replace line you mention would strip the url up to and including a # character, so:

```
http://mysite.com/Content/#Disc/index
```

would become:

```
Disc/index
```

Comment: i dont exactly know what you mean. i need the `#` as its what i use to change my history to enable back/forward buttons

Comment: You asked if the line "url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');" had anything to do with your escaping issue. I was just letting you know what that line does.

Comment: ah thanks for the info, i will try this soon, as i am on my phone at the minute

Comment: on further research this string was enough: `URLDecoder.decode(location,"UTF-8");`

Answer (score 4):

unescape is deprecated, use

```
decodeURI(url)
decodeURIComponent(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is doing the right thing. `%2F` is the HTTP-encoded `/` character, and technically speaking it should be there in the anchor tag. Locations aren't optimised for human-viewing but to be "correct".

Comment: @Ricki: I'd really recommend picking a different character: `/` in an URI is a directory separator.

Comment: bah humbug. so theres no way to do it? the HTTP encoding is not what i want to see, i want to see a '/' instead of %2F

Comment: @Ricki: You're trying to do an invalid thing.

Comment: why is this invalid? How do other sites like facebook/twitter/gmail achieve this?

Comment: @Ricki: By breaking the HTTP protocol and hacking around browser-specific techniques. The pre-HTML5 Facebook implementation is buggy, anyway; I'm not sure why you'd want to mimic that other than to look "cool".

Comment: pre-HTML5 Facebook is not what i want to mimic. Im just curious why my app doesnt react the same and if there is a way around it. The two answers below have so far produced no results. Im starting to think your right in that its not possible to do. Im not into breaking protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `urldecode()` or `rawurldecode()` in your AJAX request.

Comment: What? Explain to me how you do an AJAX request in PHP.